# Cambiar color de varios botones en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, botón, color

Me podrían ayudar con una duda en Visual Studio, estoy trabajando con C# tengo que cambiar el color de un botón pero a través de otro botón.

Así cambio para un botón

```
button1.BackColor == Color.Red;
```

El problema para mi comienza por que son 30 botones, entonces tengo que guardar el botón al que se le dio click y después con el botón de "cambiar" el botón que se le dio click cambie a otro color.

De antemano gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! No entiendo del todo la pregunta dices que es una duda de VisualBasic pero el codigo es C#? Si pones el codigo que llevas hasta el momento sera mas facil ayudarte. No termino de entender tu duda, quieres que al darle click a un boton este se cambie a rojo pero tienes 30 y no queires repetir codigo supongo? Si es asi puedes intentar hacer un delegado y un metodo generico [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/c-generic-event-handler/8263/4)

Answer (score 2):

Podria ser algo como esto

```
public class Form1 : Form1
{

    private Button btnSeleccionado = null;

    public void Form1_Load(...){

        foreach(var ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()){
            if(ctrl.Name == "btnCambiar")
                continue;

            ctrl.Click += button_Click;
        }
    }

    public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        btnSeleccionado = (Button)sender;
    }

    public void btnCambiar_Click(){

       if(btnSeleccionado != null){
          btnSeleccionado.BackColor == Color.Red;
       }
    }

}
```

Entiendo la idea es seleccionar un boton al cual cambiarle el colo con otro boton de nombre "cambiar".

En el `Form_Load` la idea es asignar el mismo evento a todos los botones (menos al de cambiar) para que al presionarlo se defina como seleccionado y sera sobre este donde aplique  el color

Veras como se usa el `sender` para conocer que boton lanzo la accion, ya que todos lanzan el mismo metodo asociado al evento click

Answer (score 0):

para solucionar tu problema hay que tener en cuenta algunas cosas. 
¿Dónde están contenidos los botones?
¿Los estás creando en tiempo de ejecución?

Suponiendo que los botones están contenidos en un panel que se llame "pnToolBox" y que hayan sido creados en tiempo de diseño, podrías usar un for each para acceder a las propiedades de cada uno de estos. Por ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

public class Form1
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control buttonX in pnToolBox.Controls)
            buttonX.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```